# jenkins - variables not visible

Tags: variables, jenkins

I am trying to display a custom message in the e-mail that is sent after the job is built. I would like to include the *svn url* and another variable *BranchId* from where the code was checked out into the email body.

I tried `SVN_URL_1` as given in the quick help on fields in the jenkins job-configure page, but it is displayed as it is in the email i.e. I get the actual string `$SVN_URL_1` and not the value.

I tried adding a environment variable as shown below

[image: Set env variable]

Output is same, I get the string as is `$BranchId`.

Any ideas how to define such variables and use them later in email message?

Comment: How are you trying to send the email? With the default email or the editable one?

Comment: @Eldad The editable one. Also tried the default email.

Comment: How do you "Set environment variables"? I also set some variables and use the editable email, and they all show. I use either the standard parameters or inject variables with the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.

Comment: @Eldad Same as `name=value` pair. And I have $name in the body textarea. But this get displayed as `$name` and not the actual value.

Comment: My question is related to the feature that you set with. Is this a plugin? Where in the project is it set? Are you able to see a parameter that was set with a regular string parameter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24433/discussion-between-mtk-and-eldad-ak)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to display the variable as `$name`, but the correct syntax of displaying any env variable/ parameter passed to the job/ env variable set as above is

```
${ENV,var="name"}
```

e.g.

```
${ENV,var="PATH"}
${ENV,var="BranchId"}
```